# Composer global, system-wide, multi-user install

Tags: php, linux, debian, composer-php

My question is quite simple to understand: I have a Debian server, where I'd like to install and use composer **and its global dependencies** in a multi-user way (like, say, RVM).

I've always managed to install composer itself, and to make it available for any user (as long as the user has shell access and +x chmod, of course).

What I would love to do, is that when I run `composer global require wp-cli/wp-cli`, the required dependency is installed in a "public" location (say /usr/local/.composer for example).

So if I set the right permissions on this directory, any user that can access /usr/local/.composer can use global dependencies.

Is that clear enough?

Someone out there with an anwser?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need? Where do you fail to pursue your goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the default directory where composer sets its global dependencies to be the one you like:

Just create the environment variable [COMPOSER_HOME](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) and make it available to all users, take a look at */etc/profile* or */etc/bash.bashrc*

```
COMPOSER_HOME="/usr/local/composer"
```

Comment: Wow, great, thanks a lot!
I guess I was too tired when I read the docs to miss that one!

Comment: Not really working for me. `echo "$COMPOSER_HOME"` gives `/usr/local/composer`, but `composer global require` still installs stuff in `~/.composer/`.

Comment: @donquixote have you exported the variable?

Comment: but this does not solve anything, this sets only my local env variables, not global ones. for all users